# C# Async call from C++ MFC app blocks gui

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, mfc

colleagues.
I have old MFC application (VC6) that extended with C# plugin. All is working very well.
But now I want to use async functions in C# plugin, but I have a problem. Problem that Windows detects GUI block. This is a picture:

[image]

C# code is FileSystemWatcher and Timer pair: so I watch for some file and return if file is not appeared in defined timeout.
If I use C# code without async\await pair all is working correctly. And what is interesting: when I use async C# code is also WORKING correctly in background. So if the file will be created and I press 'Retry' button, then I will see that C# executed successful (window with a message, db result).

This is my C# function:

```
    private static Task<(string FileName, string PublishLogCode)> CallStoredProcedure(string repoId, string guid)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<(string FileName, string PublishLogCode)>();
        var globalReportFolder = SP_CONFIG.GetLimsConfigStr("GLOBAL_REPORT_FOLDER");
        var runonce = new System.Timers.Timer() { Interval = 600000, AutoReset = false, Enabled = false }; // 30 seconds = 30000 //10 min = 600000
        runonce.Elapsed += (s, a) => 
            tcs.SetResult((FileName: "", PublishLogCode: ""));
        runonce.Start();

        if (!Directory.Exists(globalReportFolder)) //fileIOPermission.AllFiles == FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess)
            return Task.FromResult((FileName: $"<Error> Folder '{globalReportFolder}' not found", PublishLogCode: ""));

        try
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.InternalBufferSize = 65535; // to process many files simultaneously
            watcher.Path = globalReportFolder;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            //** filter files matching LabId
            watcher.Filter = $"{repoId}*.pdf";
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.Created += (s, e) =>
            {
                runonce.Stop();
                var reportFileName = $"{globalReportFolder}{e.Name}";
                tcs.SetResult(reportFileName.Contains(repoId) ? (FileName: reportFileName, PublishLogCode: InsertPublishLog(repoId, "COFA")) : ("", ""));
                watcher.Dispose();
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SP_CONFIG.WriteAuditLog($"GlobalReportRunner.StartFolderWatch", $"{e.Message}");
            tcs.SetException(e);
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

And this is function call:

```
var (reportFileName, publishLogCode) = await CallStoredProcedure(xp?.RepoId, xp?.Guid).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

In c++ I call c# function using this code (in a .tli file):

```
inline _bstr_t IOnRepoPlugin::RunPluginFunc ( _bstr_t funcName, _bstr_t funcParameters ) {
BSTR _result;
HRESULT _hr = raw_RunPluginFunc(funcName, funcParameters, &_result);
if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
return _bstr_t(_result, false);
```

}

I tried to wrap function body to a thread: it's also working in the test environment, but not in real c++ application.

This issue is not super urgent, because I have working "non-Task" code, this code is not so elegant, but it's working. However, it's interesting to figure out: why?

So, thanks in any advice.

Comment: I have the same problem when I run my external code that does authentication and my main app shows that window. I just press retry when I know it has actually finished.

Comment: The code looks fine.

Comment: The issue is in the code we cannot see. Please show the call site in your C++ code. Also state whether you need a solution that compiles with VC6. The error dialog indicates that you're communicating with a COM server that tries to call back into your code. But your code isn't dispatching messages. A [mcve] is required to address the issue.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, you are cool)) But I think for commercial software this approach is not best)

Comment: @aepot, agree. but it works not fine.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for your answer. I agree with that Task is blocking C# thread and does not dispatch gui events. But it's difficult to prepare minimal working example, because there are c++ project, interface and c# project. So, for now, it's cheaper to keep C# code in synchronous style.
I have edited original message and demonstrate how I call c# from c++

Comment: It seems that your C++ is synchronously waiting for the asynchronous function call to retire. That doesn't buy you anything. It's the moral equivalent of spinning up a thread, and then synchronously waiting for that thread to run to completion. If you want to benefit from asynchronous calls, the caller has to be prepared for that. In doing so there's a high chance that this will also resolve the *"Server Busy"* issue by handing control back to the framework that can then continue to run its message loop and dispatch callbacks from the COM server.

Comment: I watch with interest. Mine is for Google Calendar OAuth to work. So I have to wait for it to finish. But maybe it can wait more elegantly. I’ll see how your question goes for now.

Comment: Wow.  MFC.  It  has been a really, really long time since I had to deal with this.  I remember dealing with this error way back when.    I cannot tell you off the top of my head how to solve this but I suggest playing around with the `COleMessageFilter` class, in particular the `SetMessagePendingDelay` function.  You might need to call `AfxOleGetMessageFilter` to actually get the object.   (Note that I'm operating under the assumption that somewhere in the background, COM has been initialized.  I could be wrong...)